# many wrapping functions in C

Tags: c, function, macros, word-wrap

My C header file contains about 300 various functions, their names all beginning with "foo_db_" and accepting a "db_t" as their first parameter (knowing what is exactly a db_t is no really relevant here, it's just a struct).

```
function foo_db_my_first_function(db_t *db, char *param1, int param2);
function foo_db_my_second_function(db_t *db, double param1, const char *param2, int param3);
(...)
function foo_db_my_Nth_function(db_t *db, int param1);
```

My job is to write another 300 wrapping functions named "foo_XXXX" (XXXX begin the suffix of the "foo_db_" function) with a default value for the first parameter.

```
static __inline function foo_my_first_function(char *param1, int param2) {
  foo_db_my_first_function(DEFAULT_DB, param1, param2);
}
(...)
```

I was wondering if I could write some macros to ease my job: declare the "db" function and the corresponding "default" function (without the first parameter).

**Unfortunately, I cannot use C99 and variadic macros arguments :(** so I think I'm screwed :), but I prefer to ask first here before burning my fingers to write those 300 functions :/

Comment: Either write a shell/perl/python script, or punch the lead developer in the face for screwing up the design?

Comment: OMG, I cannot show this thread to my boss anymore :)

Comment: vim macros would probably make short work of this

Comment: @Guid If he reads this, he deserves this for inventing (or at least allowing) such a structure. 300 functions?! Without `<stdargs.h>`? :-O

Comment: it is a central file, and it is a legacy of more than 14 years of development, you can't imagine what a lazy developper (and many of them have touched this code) can do when he doesn't want to bother factorizing some code and prefer just add his little function.

Comment: Never underestimate the power of creative laziness. It isn't always a sin, either. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the original header file for the API is regular enough, then a script in your favorite text processing language (Perl, [Lua](http://www.lua.org), Python, Awk, or even /bin/sh in a pinch) will likely be the simplest approach.

Your script would collect all public function declarations using a regex or simple text matching to identify them (likely based on the `foo_db_` prefix). It could then write two output files. First, a suitable `.h` file declaring your wrappers, and second the `.c` source file implementing them by stuffing `DEFAULT_DB` into their first parameter. You will need to do a minimal amount of work to copy the rest of the parameters through, but with luck the declarations are all regular enough that the text manipulation can be as simple as "rest of line" or the like.

Having done that, I would check the script into revision control, and get it invoked at build time, treating the generated files as transient build products. However, if you don't have a sufficiently flexible build system (this is why I still perfer `make` to nearly everything else I've seen proposed) then you will have to find a suitable kludge to signal that your generated default wrappers are out of date when the API changes.

This approach will require investing some time in the code generator script, but you should be ahead on that well before the time you imagine hand-coding your 100th wrapper. And the second time you run it....

In extreme cases, you could end up needing to implement much of the front-end of a C compiler. In that case, I see two approaches that are both more socially acceptable than arranging a meeting with the architect in a dark alley. First, there is a GCC back-end that emits its AST in XML; the resulting XML is a bear, but has been reduced down to a tree of tokens that can be manipulated. Second, there is always [LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/), a full parser that is easily used from Lua (and I suspect that there are other PEG parsers out there for other scripting languages too). Sample code for LPeg that lexes and parses C is [referenced at the Wiki page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LpegRecipes).

Comment: cmake is used for the build chain (and, by the way, I just discovered Qbs which offer awesome things o_O but it is out of subject here), I think I could integrate the wrapper generator somewhere but I'll have to convince the boss..

Comment: I've not personally used CMAKE, but I know it is very powerful. I am continually surprised at the number of build tools i've encountered that don't make it possible to generate C code for later compilation in a project. Does no one use LEX and YACC any more? Or write Perl scripts to create initialized arrays from compact expressions?

Comment: Isn't it a better solution to generate only a .h with __inline wrapper functions?

Comment: I'd tend to agree that `__inline` seems attractive. For this scale of wrapper, it probably is even a win, and the similar approach that generates wrapper macros instead is probably also a win. The catch with inline wrappers really happens when the wrapper conceals a lot of work to transform multiple arguments and the wrappers get widely used. It wouldn't be that hard to try it both ways and measure, but my hunch would be that in this case inline wrappers are a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in Excel.  Create a cell with "foo_db_ (db_t *db)", drag it down as many places as you need, fill in all the blanks, then copy it all into your program (you can test that the copy will work ahead of time, but I just tried with Notepad and it seems to work as intended).  Now you have all your function headers, and can fill in the rest from there.